# How to fix "Failed to compile. ./node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.min.js 1947:29"

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, npm-install, plyr, failed-to-connect

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.min.js 1947:29
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1947:29)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         let e = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : !1;
|         if (e ? _this2.scrollPosition = {
>           x: window.scrollX ?? 0,
|           y: window.scrollY ?? 0
|         } : window.scrollTo(_this2.scrollPosition.x, _this2.scrollPosition.y), document.body.style.overflow = e ? "hidden" : "", R(_this2.target, _this2.player.config.classNames.fullscreen.fallback, e), M.isIos) {
```

When i run my projuct "npm start", then this error is coming, i tried delete "node_modules" and installed "npm install" but still getting this error, can any one please help me.

My react version is: 18.0.0
Node: v16.13.0
Npm v: 8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:**
Run the following command to clear the npm cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

**Step-2:**
Delete the "package-lock.json" file from your project directory.

**Step-3:**
Reinstall dependencies by running following command:

```
npm install
```

Comment: Hi, Maulik, tried this, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Update your tsconfig.json file . and make sure the `target` property is set to **ES5** :

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", //this line 
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
```

And make sure the `jsx` property  is set to `react-jsx` :  `"jsx": "react-jsx"`

**NOTE :** make sure you're using latest version of `react-scripts(v5)`

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}

Comment: Hi, monim And my react script version is: "react-scripts": "4.0.3",

Comment: could you try adding :  **"browserslist": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"],** to your **package.json**

Comment: Yes, "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],

Comment: Not production but browserlist

Comment: "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },