# I want to import Css Baseline from @mui/material , which is there in my json but i get'@mui/material' should be listed in the project's dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, npm, material-ui

I want to import Css Baseline from @mui/material , which is there in my json  but i get'@mui/material' should be listed in the project's dependencies.What should I do been stuck here for a while now!

```
{
  "name": "time_pass",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@alan-ai/alan-sdk-web": "^1.8.44",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.12.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
```

I tried installing @mui/materials specifically using npm i -S @mui/material
still its a no go.

Comment: I guess the issue is with the installation: Go through this solution and let me know: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340077/21957513

Comment: You have `@mui/material` in your dependencies. And you said, that you have installed it. Can you provide us with the code, which shows how you try to import CSS Baseline? Is it the same way as it is described in the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/)?

Answer (score 0):

If `"npm install @mui/material"` is not working, you can try to reinstall the dependencies by running

> npm install

again and deleting the **'node_modules'** folder in your project to ensure a clean installation. Make sure and verify that you are using an updated version of Node.js by running the `"npm --version"`in your command line.